# Limiting user attributes from AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory

We stored some personal data in the user profile attribute, we donot want to show these personal details attribute to normal users. Developer while implementing the powerapps or graph api application they are able to pull the user all attribute details. We noticed Office365.Getprofile ,office365.searchusers() function and graph API calls are pulling the all user attributes details. How to block group of people to read these attributes

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently an option to completely hide specific user information in the portal. Here are the closest options available:

1. You can use Microsoft Graph / PowerShell to [prevent users from reading other users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions) in the directory by setting "Read other users" to $false.    This setting is available in Microsoft Graph and PowerShell only. Setting this flag to $false  but some information will still be accessible in other services such as Exchange Online.
2. You can prevent users from accessing the Microsoft Entra portal under Microsoft Entra ID > Users > User settings > "Restrict access to Microsoft Entra ID administration portal"
3. You have the option to restrict guest user access under Microsoft Entra ID > Users > User Settings
   [image]